# Excel VBA looping infinitely

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm quite new to VBA

I'm getting an infinite loop with the code below, when I'm expecting the search to stop on reaching the last occurrence. (I have 2 cells in the current workspace that contain >>>). Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

```
Set titles = Range("A1:A1")
Dim bEndLoop As Boolean
bEndLoop = False
' lookup part of content in search
mCurLookup = xlPart
With possibleTitles
    Do While Not bEndLoop
        Set titles = .Find(What:=">>>", After:=ActiveCell)
        If Not titles Is Nothing Then
               Application.Goto titles, True
                MsgBox (titles.Address)
                titles.Activate
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
                bEndLoop = True
            End If
    ' Set t2 = titles(1).CurrentRegion
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: If the value is found there is nothing in your code to tell the loop to stop. The usual way is to store the address of the first found cell and then check against that for future found values.

Comment: @SJR I was expecting that the titles.activate command would move the active cell down in the sheet, and that the After:=ActiveCell would tell the Find command to look only after the active cell. Then I was expecting that after the last cell containing ">>>", the Find would find nothing, and the loop would exit.

Answer (score 2):

guess the answer should look like this (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext )
I don't like the 2-part Find then FindNext (can't I have just one loop?), but then if it's the official way of doing it I guess it's better to stick to that.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
     Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = 5
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If c is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
End With
```

Comment: @Tom no you can't. If `c` *is* `Nothing` then `c.Address` will throw error 91. VBA logical operators don't short-circuit, and if they did you'd still have to check for `Is Nothing` first.

Comment: When using `Find` I would recommend specifying more parameters.

Comment: FWIW I've committed changes to that documentation file in my fork, [here](https://github.com/retailcoder/VBA-Docs/blob/excel-api/api/Excel.Range.FindNext.md). The "official way" is weirdly written. I'll include these changes in a broader pull request some time this week.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of your code using a `Find` `FindNext` method. Using this method is far faster then using a `For` Loop equivalent

```
Dim titles As Range
Dim possibleTitles As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Set possibleTitles = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

With possibleTitles
    Set titles = .Find(what:=">>>")
    If Not titles Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = titles.Address

        Do
            MsgBox titles.Address
            Set titles = .FindNext(titles)
        Loop Until firstAddress = titles.Address
    End If
End With
```

Comment: The ActiveSheet.Range("A:A") does not work for me (in my case it was "B:B"). It only worked when I change it to ("B1:K100") . I have 2 matching cell addresses on B column and one on C

Comment: @Francis - You may need to change it to your applicable range